# table row not getting created in jquery loop

Tags: jquery

Table data is not getting created inside for loop. Sample code`

```
var SelectedIndex = $(this).index();
          $.getJSON('QueryPhpFile.php?requ=getshopcategory&ShopId='+ShopId[SelectedIndex], function(data) 
          {
             $('#id_div_Item').show();
             $('#id_div_Item').empty();
             var table='<table>';
             $.each(data.JsonArray, function(key, val) 
             {  
               table=table+'<tr>';
               table=table+'<td class="id_td_ItemHeader">';
               table=table+val.vc_CategoryName;
               table=table+'</td>';
               table=table+'</tr>';
               $.getJSON('QueryPhpFile.php?requ=getshopitem&ShopId='+ShopId[SelectedIndex]+'&CategoryId='+val.vc_CategoryId, function(data) 
               {
                 $.each(data.JsonArray, function(key, val) 
                 {  
                   console.log("ItemNames" + val.vc_ItemName);
                   table=table+'<tr>';
                   table=table+'<td class="id_td_ItemHeader">';
                   table=table+val.vc_ItemName;
                   table=table+'</td>';
                   table=table+'</tr>';
                 });

               });

             });
             $('#id_div_Item').append(table);
             $('#id_div_Item').append('</table>');           
          });`
```

This rows are not coming. Only rows before the below loop part is coming. any idea or suggestions to correct this. thanks

```
console.log("ItemNames" + val.vc_ItemName);
                   table=table+'<tr>';
                   table=table+'<td class="id_td_ItemHeader">';
                   table=table+val.vc_ItemName;
                   table=table+'</td>';
                   table=table+'</tr>';
```

Comment: Can you verify that the second getJSON call is succeeding?

Comment: Hi Joe,console.log("ItemNames" + val.vc_ItemName);

Comment: Data coming in console.log correctly. only row not getting created